# How to call onUserLeaveHint when the system navigation are by gestures?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile, picture-in-picture

at this moment I am implementing the picture in picture feature for android, as the documentation says we should enter in the picture in picture mode when the user leaves the app through the home button with the method onUserLeaveHint() it works as expected in devices with physical buttons, but when the phone has not and work with gestures like the iPhone the method onUserLeaveHint is not called, so is there a way to catch or simulate that behavior?

Answer (score 1):

`onUserLeaveHint()` is not a reliable Android lifecycle callback to detect "Home" button clicks. Even though the official documentation specifies that you can use it to detect "when the user presses the Home key", I have found this to be false.

For example, `onUserLeaveHint()` might be called when the an Android native dialog is prompted, or when you start another Activity.
Also, as for the example you have mentioned, I have also found that when Gesture Navigation is enabled (Android 11 and above) and the user goes to "Recents" and then exists app - `onUserLeaveHint()` will not be called.

Unfortunately, until this day I have not found any air-tight way to detect "Home" button clicks in Android. I guess that OS designers do not want app developers to detect this easily.